# Get or calculate jam factor for entire city (particularly, Moscow)

Tags: here-api

The task is to get jam factor for the entire city (Moscow). Like it is shown on Yandex Maps https://yandex.ru/maps/213/moscow/?l=trf%2Ctrfe&ll=37.787312%2C55.833826&z=9.42 , but with free API that way, server can handle and process.

I've searched free APIs and the best (and only) I found, was https://here.com. But it has not suitable endpoint for my task. There is only https://traffic.api.here.com/traffic/6.1/flow.json endpoint that returns much great info, including JF fields -- jam factors for every street in the area. But I can't convert it in jam factor for entire city (that is mentioned in radio or TV news and so on). If I take average or root mean square, it differs a lot with the counter from YandexMaps and TV News.

1) Maybe there is another endpoint in HERE.API, that returns jam factor for entire city, not for every street?

2) Or can you suggest a method or formula to calculate JF for the city from data returned by one of existing HERE.API endpoints?

3) Or can you suggest any another free API, that gives jam factor for Moscow. Or even commercial API. I've explored Yandex.API. It has interactive maps with traffic schemas on it, but I haven't discovered a way to get JW factor for backend API with it.

Answer (score 0):

The HERE Traffic API provides jam factors of different roads in a specified location and at this moment does not provide a single jam factor for a whole city. Calculating the average jam factor from the HERE Traffic API did not match the ones from the other companies because you do not know which roads were taken into consideration in their calculations.